# Get UI button clicked on CK Editor toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have built a very simple plugin for CK Editor (because apparently that's the only way to add a custom button to the toolbar?)

I'd like to know how I can get the DOM ID of my custom button when it is clicked (or any object representative of the button which will allow me to create a jQuery object)

```
(function () {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin', {
        icons: 'myicon',
        hidpi: true,
        init: function (editor) {

            editor.addCommand('mycommand', {
                exec : function(editor) {
                    // get button information
                }
            });

            editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton('MyCommand', {
                label: 'Custom Action',
                command: 'mycommand',
                toolbar: 'insert,5',
                icon: 'myicon'
            });

        }

    });
})();
```

I'd like to attach my own custom UI element to the toolbar when the button is clicked and I need a relative anchor point in order to display it in the correct position on the screen.

I'm using CK Editor 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can access the button with the following code (using jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', '.cke_button__mycommand', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

You can inspect the toolbar with your browser to get more information.